# Cannot delete a column that contains multiple tables

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever I have two tables in the same column, I get this error.

[image]

1. Create a table in columns (ie B1:C3)
2. Create another table below that table (ie B5:C7)
3. Right-click on column B

   - Is the "Delete" option grayed out (unavailable)?
4. Convert the second table (B5:C7) back to a normal area
5. Right-click on column B

   - Is the "Delete" option active (black) now?

It is for me.

I don't understand why it happens but I'd really appreciate if someone could confirm that I'm not alone on this one. This actually seems like a bug.

Comment: It is 'behavior by design'. A ListObject (aka *structured* ) table has many internal mechanisms. The Delete (column) command is not designed to enumerate through all of the ListObjects on the worksheet to see if any intersect with the column being deleted and then spawn subprocesses that deal with deleting table columns specifically. Instead, it simply does not allow the Delete command when more than a single ListObject table is involved.

Comment: Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. :) I've already figured out that my "solution" will be to loop all tables in the specific column that should be deleted, and save their addresses (minus one column!) and table names. Then I'll unlist all those tables, delete the column and then recreate all the tables again. Quite a decent workaround if I may say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is 'behavior by design'. A ListObject (aka structured ) table has many internal mechanisms. The Delete (column) command is not designed to enumerate through all of the ListObjects on the worksheet to see if any intersect with the column being deleted and then spawn subprocesses that deal with deleting table columns specifically while simultaneously keeping in mind how that will affect other ListObject tables. Instead, it simply does not allow the Delete command when more than a single ListObject table is involved.

Comment: May I correct you: this is 'behavior by BAD design' :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not allowed may be because deleting a column will Shift Cells Why Dont you try deleting by selecting one column of a Table [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7xTw.jpg)

see the screenshot you can do it if you select one column of a table at a time
Thanks

Comment: This does not address the reason why you can delete a full column if it intersects a single table but not more than one table.

Comment: but the answer gives a clue that you can do it by selecting one table at a time

Comment: Good idea. However, because I'm having more tables in other columns in the same worksheet, one cannot delete a table column like you suggested. Let's say there's three tables = B1:C3, B5:C7 and F2:G8. Try deleting a table column in the first table. It won't work.

Comment: @TAKL - that's a different situation from the original. Deleting a column in the first table would obviously make a malformed third table. Let's try to address the situation in your question; edit your question to add other scenarios if you must.

Answer (score 1):

Try organizing your data in a different way, so these problems don't occur.

There is no compelling reason to have several tables on **ONE** sheet. If table placement presents a problem with row/column management, consider moving tables to separate sheets.

Tables can be referenced in formulas by the table name. Ditto for table columns, so there really is no reason to keep several tables on one sheet if you need flexibility with row and column management.

**Edit after comment** The fact that users are working with several tables and cannot be expected to change sheets to maintain data on different sheets can be addressed in different ways:

1. Educate your user. I'm a big fan of teaching people how to use software. If they understand what they are doing, they feel positive. If you keep them dumb and tell them to "just click there and shut up" they may feel negative.
2. You may want to re-consider your data architecture. Provide your users with an interface to add/edit/delete records that is independent of where the data is stored. This is 2016. Data input and data storage are not married to the same page.

You are posting your question in a site for enthusiast programmers. A little bit of VBA will separate your data entry/data storage issues, if you are interested to work it out.

Comment: The compelling reason in this case is that it's easier to work with these tables when they're placed in one sheet. If I'd follow your suggestion (one table per sheet), the users would have more than 10 sheets to switch between in order to add or remove data. Another idea would be to NOT create tables out of all these data types but I find it really easy to work with tables when coding.

Comment: You may want to re-consider your data architecture. Provide your users with an interface to add/edit/delete records that is independent of where the data is stored.  This is 2016. Data input and data storage are not married to the same page. Use the tools.

Comment: I simply haven't thought of using an interface for adding/editing/deleting records. It's quite simple and I'll have no problem rewriting code. Don't ask why but it's been so common here that people see the (data holding) table that they need to change and change it. Thanks for your advice!